# SQL grouping together so data does not repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, grouping, cross-join

Have data in a table, and trying to query it out so the data reads for example like Motrin | mg | 25 | 4 | day | Pain, in one row.  from the image...i have them all under the Answer column.  My query that i have brings them all out...but it repeats the data.  Can anyone help with grouping this under the DrilldownQuestionID?

Below is the sample data i created:

| PracticeID | PatientID | ParentPageID | ParentPageNumber | QuestionID | DrilldownQuestionID | DrilldownAnsRecordID | EncounterID | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2091 | 1 | encounter1 | Tylenol |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2092 | 1 | encounter1 | mg |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2093 | 1 | encounter1 | 500 |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2094 | 1 | encounter1 | 3 |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2095 | 1 | encounter1 | day |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2096 | 1 | encounter1 | Headache |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2091 | 2 | encounter1 | Motrin |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2092 | 2 | encounter1 | mg |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2093 | 2 | encounter1 | 25 |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2094 | 2 | encounter1 | 4 |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2095 | 2 | encounter1 | day |
| 1 | 111111 | 48 | 5 | 1475 | 2096 | 2 | encounter1 | Pain |

my query below is what I have;

```
    select distinct j.Answer as Name, 
    n.Answer as Dosage,
    k.Answer as [Dosage Unit], 
    o.Answer as [How Many],
    l.Answer as [How Often], 
    m.Answer as [Taken For]
from
    (select isnull(a.[Answer],'') as Answer, 
        a.EncounterID  
    from C_ItemDrillDown c join D_AWVAnswers a 
        on c.ItemDrilldownID = a.DrilldownQuestionID 
        and a.QuestionID = 1475 
        and a.DrilldownQuestionID = 2091
    where a.EncounterID = @EncounterID) as j
        join
    (select isnull(a.[Answer],'') as Answer, 
        a.EncounterID  
    from C_ItemDrillDown c join D_AWVAnswers a 
        on c.ItemDrilldownID = a.DrilldownQuestionID 
        and a.QuestionID = 1475 
        and a.DrilldownQuestionID = 2093
    where a.EncounterID = @EncounterID) as n
        on j.EncounterID = n.EncounterID
        join
    (select isnull(a.[Answer],'') as Answer, 
        a.EncounterID 
    from C_ItemDrillDown c join D_AWVAnswers a 
        on c.ItemDrilldownID = a.DrilldownQuestionID 
        and a.QuestionID = 1475 
        and a.DrilldownQuestionID = 2092
    where a.EncounterID = @EncounterID) as k
        on n.encounterID = k.EncounterID
        join
    (select isnull(a.[Answer],'') as Answer, 
        a.EncounterID  
    from C_ItemDrillDown c join D_AWVAnswers a 
        on c.ItemDrilldownID = a.DrilldownQuestionID 
        and a.QuestionID = 1475 
        and a.DrilldownQuestionID = 2094
    where a.EncounterID = @EncounterID) as o
        on k.EncounterID = o.EncounterID
        join
    (select isnull(a.[Answer],'') as Answer, 
        a.EncounterID 
    from C_ItemDrillDown c join D_AWVAnswers a 
        on c.ItemDrilldownID = a.DrilldownQuestionID 
        and a.QuestionID = 1475 
        and a.DrilldownQuestionID = 2095
    where a.EncounterID = @EncounterID) as l
        on o.encounterID = l.EncounterID
        join
    (select isnull(a.[Answer],'') as Answer, 
        a.EncounterID 
    from C_ItemDrillDown c join D_AWVAnswers a 
        on c.ItemDrilldownID = a.DrilldownQuestionID 
        and a.QuestionID = 1475 
        and a.DrilldownQuestionID = 2096
    where a.EncounterID = @EncounterID) as m
        on l.encounterID = m.EncounterID
```

What i would like as a result is:

| Name | Dosage | Dosage Unit | How Many | How Often | Taken For |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tylenol | 500 | mg | 3 | day | Headache |
| Motrin | 25 | mg | 4 | day | Pain |

Comment: Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. No one can copy/paste data from a picture. As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: There is no repeating data in your result, each row is unique. Please explain, by providing sample data and the result you want to achieve as editable text, what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: your image is not showing. So please write down what you wanted to show

Comment: @stu thank you for your advice.  i hope the edits i made to this question will help and someone will be able to help me out.

Comment: @NickW thank you for your advice.  i hope the edits i made to this question will help and someone will be able to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you're after straight-forward pivot, something like the following:

```
select 
  max(case when DrilldownQuestionID = 2091 then Answer end) [Name],
  max(case when DrilldownQuestionID = 2092 then Answer end) [Dosage Unit],
  max(case when DrilldownQuestionID = 2093 then Answer end) Dosage,
  max(case when DrilldownQuestionID = 2094 then Answer end) [How Many],
  max(case when DrilldownQuestionID = 2095 then Answer end) [How Often],
  max(case when DrilldownQuestionID = 2096 then Answer end) [Taken For]
from t
group by DrilldownAnsRecordID;
```

I've omitted the redundant (to the problem) columns which you would also group-by if you needed to use them.

Result:

[image]

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53220b8f96100463caff023c020b325e)